# Printer not printing with full ink paper comes out blank, is it motherboard ?

Tags: printer

Have a rx520 Epson printer tried.. ied scanning a document it takes the paper through and makes printing noises bit paper comes out blank.

I then tried printing a document from pc same issue paper comes out blank.

I have tried : shaking inks and putting them in, aligning print heads, cleaning print heads, replacing cartridges they are now all full and display as so on the printer

Really stumped now could it be a circuit board which has gone?

I have had it around 8 years..

Comment: Has anything else changed with your computer between when it works and when it does not (i.e. PC change, driver change, hardware change, etc.)?

Comment: Carnt remember it doing.. I have completely disconnected it from pc to use it as a stand alone scanner to rule out pc but still no difference..  I assume that would be the correct way to rule out pc being issue?

Comment: Does a printer test page show that all the jets are working? How long ago was the printer last working (inkjets need to be used regularly)?

Comment: Test page prints blank which is the confusing part even though I have replaced all inks a day a go..

Comment: If the test page is blank, then it looks as if the print head has failed. Either all jets are blocked, or the electrical connections have failed.